# Calling User Defined Function In User Defined Class

Tags: php, function, class, methods

I am trying to create a custom class that will handle mailing for me.

Here is my class (mailerclass.php) :

```
class Mailer {

        // Private fields
        private $to;
        private $subject;
        private $message;

        // Constructor function
        function __construct($to, $subject, $message) {
            $to = $to;
            $subject = $subject;
            $message = $message;
        }   

        // Function to send mail with constructed data.
        public function SendMail() {

            if (mail($to, $subject, $messagecontent)) {
                return "Success";
            }
            else {
                return "Failed";    
            }           
        }

    }
```

When I try to call it here (index.php) I get a "Call to undefined function SendMail()" message?

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        // Import class
        include('mailerclass.php');

        // Trim and store data
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);


        // Store mail data
        if ($validated == true) {

            // Create new instance of mailer class with user data
            $mailer = new Mailer($to, $subject, $message);          

            // Send Mail and store result
            $result = $mailer.SendMail();
        }
```

Why does this happen ??

Comment: `$mailer->sendMail()` . In php you call methods using the arrow (`->`) not the dot (`.`) the dot (`.`) is used to CONCATENATE in php.

Comment: Start here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php in PHP you use '->' not '.' to access methods, properties of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call class methods with a dot. You call class methods (not static) with `->` like:

```
$result = $mailer->SendMail();
```

Besides you need to set your properties with `$this->` (again if not static) change the content of your contstructor to:

```
$this->to = $to;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->message = $message;
```

Same goes for your `mail()` function:

```
mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->messagecontent)
```

You saw me mentioning static a few times, if you ever want to access a static property or method in your class you can use `self::`

Answer (score 1):

Dot `.` is use for `concatenate`. You use `->` to access member of class

```
$result = $mailer->SendMail();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a contact operator, to access member of a class both variable and functions use `->` operator
use the below code:
`$result = $mailer->SendMail();`